# How to drag and drop using jquery between different Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I want to make Drag & drop web builder. I am using the script to drag and drop the images from one place to another. but they are placing after then other. I need the script to freely place where ever I want. 
The script I am using is ""

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#dvSource img").draggable({
revert: "invalid",
refreshPositions: true,
drag: function (event, ui) {
ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
},
stop: function (event, ui) {
ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {

}
else {

}
}
});
$("#dvDest").droppable({
drop: function (event, ui) {
if ($("#dvDest img").length == 0) {
$("#dvDest").html("");
}
ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
$("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
}
});
});
</script>



and 


<pre lang="xml"><div id="dvSource">
<img alt="" src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" />
<img alt="" src="images/Desert.jpg" />
<img alt="" src="images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
<img alt="" src="images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
<img alt="" src="images/Koala.jpg" />
<img alt="" src="images/Lighthouse.jpg" />
<img alt="" src="images/Penguins.jpg" />
<img alt="" src="images/Tulips.jpg" />
</div>
<hr />
<div id="dvDest">
Drop here
</div></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign one id to your body tag like

```
<body id="bdy">
```

change your droppable code with body id, see in following

```
$("#bdy").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            if ($("#bdy img").length == 0) {
                $("#bdy").html("");
            }
            ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
            $("#bdy").append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually I want to develop the Drag & Drop CMS. The magazine creator. Is it Good technique to use JQUERYUI ?

Comment: is above code useful to you? pl tick correct to accept answer.